# How can I delete files or directories that match any of the patterns in "Users|folder|oer"?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, ksh

I need finds specific words in lines, which I will use to delete that line. I have a script like this:

```
# Find Users, oer or folder ( Users | oer | folder ) -> delete
HELP_DIR="Users|folder|oer"
find . | sed '/'"${HELP_DIR}"'/d'
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to delete files/directories that have certain words in their file names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Find with ERE

Use find with extended regular expressions and alternation. For example:

```
find -E . -regex '.*(User|folder|oer).*' -exec rm {} +
```